# searchSource not found (Elasticsearch-Watcher JAVA API)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-watcher

I am trying to create a new watcher using PUTWatch API of JAVA ElasticSearch. I am following 
[this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/api-java.html) to create it. From that link:

```
 SearchRequest request = Requests.searchRequest("idx").source(searchSource()
    .query(filteredQuery(matchQuery("response", 404), boolFilter()
        .must(rangeFilter("date").gt("{{ctx.trigger.scheduled_time}}"))
        .must(rangeFilter("date").lt("{{ctx.execution_time}}")))));
```

When I try the same , I am getting `The method searchSource is not defined`.  Can somebody help me?